# How to disable navigation buttons if at the first/last record in a form

Tags: vba, ms-access, navigation

In MS Access 2007 I want to be able to disable a navigation button on a form.

Pseudo Code as follows

```
If at the first record Then
Disable Previous button

ElseIf at the last record Then
Disable the Next button
```

I believe it has something to do with the Current event. Although I just not sure on the specific logic.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my databases, Access already does this with the record navigator.  Could you just use that instead?

Comment: I'm using custom button. This is meant to be used by non IT users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access disables the previous and next buttons on a normal navigation pane by default if your at the beginning or end of a recordset.

If your using custom navigation buttons then you can use

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    cmdPrevious.Enabled = Not (CurrentRecord = 1)
    cmdNext.Enabled = Not (CurrentRecord = DCount(AnyField, RecordSource))
End Sub
```

Comment: Great code, but how would i do it for a subform when i have
`Me!processSurveysubFormA.Form.Recordset.MoveNext`